# some vector calculus frequently occurs in the study of PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

As I work through PDE by L.C. Evans, as well as reading papers in the literature of linear/nonlinear PDE. The terms "inward pointing normal" and "outward pointing normal"frequently occur. For instance, in Evans, inward normal is used most often. Whereas in the research of Naviers-STokes equations, outward normal is more often used. As a beginner, I am quite vague about when to use which. Could anyone explain to me and give me some examples that help demonstrating the difference so that we can use the right term in the right situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Normal is short for normal vector of a surface. If the surface has two sides  (not a Möbius strip or whatever) the surface has a inner and outer side and one can choose the normal vector inward or outward. This plays a role if you look at a flux through a surface.

Comment: I know that the difference from first year calculus. But I need examples that helps me to apply the right one to the right situation.

Comment: your question is not answerable in general. To answer which is "in" or "out" the context matters. Generally, the choice is just one of contextual convention. For example, for compact surfaces traditionally the outward pointing normal is taken to be positive. Here inward is the side of the surface which contains a finite volume.

Comment: Study some boundary problems from physics and engineering, like solidification fronts or gas bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you are talking about normal vectors to surfaces in 3d-space. A similar discussion holds for curves in the plane.
Firstly, there it is not always obvious what is meant by "outward" versus "inward". Consider a plane, for example. Even though this surface has two different "sides", it is not clear which should be called the "outside" and which the "inside". In general, the choice of which side of a surface to call the "outside" is called "choosing an orientation". (There are some surfaces which are not orientable, in the sense that they only have "one side", eg. the Mobius strip and Klein bottle but I assume you do not need to worry about those for now)

If, however, you are talking about normal vectors to something like a sphere or an ellipsoid in 3d-space, then there is a natural intuitive choice of which direction to call "outward", and this should be apparent as soon as you draw a picture of the surface.

However, I do not think it is true that you will automatically find the "outward" vector whenever you try to find the normal.

For example, consider the unit sphere in 3d-space. This surface can be described by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. A common way to find a normal vector at, say, the point $(1,0,0)$, is to find the gradient of the function $F(x,y,z)= x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ at that point. This gives you the vector $(2,0,0)$, and indeed this looks like an "outward" normal vector, since from the point $(1,0,0)$ this vector points toward the "outside" of the sphere.
However, the same surface is described by the equation $-x^2 -y^2 -z^2 = -1$. If we use the same process to find a normal at (1,0,0), we get the vector $(-2,0,0)$, which points "inwards".

How do you know whether you've found the outward or the inward normal? Here's one recipe: I assume you're looking at a surface defined by an equation like $F(x,y,z)=c$, where c is a constant and F is a (differentiable) function of three variables. There's a similar recipe for parametric surfaces or curves, which I'd be happy to elaborate on if necessary.

- Sketch the surface; if there's a natural choice of what "outward"
  means, then it should be obvious from your sketch.
- Find a formula for a normal at an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$ using the
  gradient of the function F.
- Choose a point on your surface (if possible, a nice one like the
  origin, or a point on a coordinate axis, to simplify the
  calculations). Plug the coordinates of that point into the formula
  for the normal that you found in second step.
- On your sketch, draw the vector that you found in third step
- based at the point that you chose. If it points in the "outward"
  direction, good. If not, go back to the formula you found in second step
  and multiply it by $-1$. (As you say, this is how you go from "outward"
  to "inward", and vice versa)
- As long as your surface is "nice"---and if you're in, say, vector calculus stuff,
  almost all surfaces you see will fall into this category---then the
  formula you now have will give you an outward normal at *every* point
  on the surface, not just at the one you tested in third step.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I will take some time and read this comprehensive answer.

Comment: I found the recipe in your last few sentence sensible. Could you please provide an example to demonstrate?